# Реализация автоматического обновления ссылки с промежутком

Tags: веб-программирование, android, gps

День добрый, предположим я принимаю кордионаты с GPS долгота & широта, возможно ли эти кордионаты на сервер отправлять скажем по ссылке:
http://mygpscord/mycord_new/$долгота/$широта проблема в том что-бы эта ссылка постоянно вызывалась с промежутком там в 3 секунды например

Пишу из под Eclipse =) Только учусь программировать на Android. Так что сильно не ругайте. Лучше полную статью как это сделать =) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз Вы учитесь советую разбираться самостоятельно по шагам, найдите пример по работе с `GPS`, потом пример `Http GET` запроса, используйте `AsyncTask` для создания отдельного потока, в котором будете запрос делать. Для повторения запроса можно организовать бесконечный цикл с паузой перед следующей итерацией.
Попробуйте написать код, если возникнут конкретные ошибки, обращайтесь за помощью.

Comment: Спасибо как раз что нужно, теперь знаю в какую сторону копать нужно.